# Docusaurus: Getting a syntax error on straight forward link

Tags: jsx, docusaurus, mdxjs

I'm getting the following syntax errors:

```
3:02:58 PM: SyntaxError: /opt/build/repo/docs/Flow/c-flo-Pages_Components_Checkbox_2005eb3f-280e-48da-94aa-5075bc92edb6.md: Unterminated JSX contents. (125:16)
3:02:58 PM:   123 | <p><a parentName="p" {...{"href":"/docs/Flow/c-flo-Pages_Components_State_saving_e52d1bd0-576e-433f-980b-acc14db70533"}}>{`Saving state data in components`}</a></p>
3:02:58 PM:   124 | <p><a parentName="p" {...{"href":"/docs/Flow/c-flo-Client_Side_Validation_63626730-3fe3-4260-8716-736d1b07cdea"}}>{`Client-side validation`}</a></p>
3:02:58 PM: > 125 |     </MDXLayout>
3:02:58 PM:       |                 ^
3:02:58 PM:   126 |   )
3:02:58 PM:   127 | };
3:02:58 PM:   128 | MDXContent.isMDXComponent = true
```

The code at that spot is:

```
[Text component](c-flo-Pages_Components_Text_204907e5-ba9a-4695-8192-64aa83f08e74.md)
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this would be causing this error?

Many Thanks!